# Characterisation of norm convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $X$ be a Hilbert space and $(x_n)\in X^{\mathbb N}$ be a sequence. Then the following statements are equivalent (with $x \in X$):

1. We have $x_n \to x$, i.e. $\| x_n -x \| \to 0$ and
2. we have $x_n \xrightarrow{\sigma} x$ (weak convergence) as well as $\|x_n\| \to \|x\|$.

Proof: Just expand the expression $\|x_n - x\|^2 = (x_n - x, x_n - x)$.

**Q1**: This is not true in arbitrary Banach spaces (correct?). Is there a nice example?

**Q2**: Does the above characterisation still hold for certain spaces which are not (pre-)Hilbertian? Does it still hold for $L^p$ with $p \ne 2$ e.g.?

edit: Apparently, this is referred to as the Radon–Riesz property, Kadets–Klee property or property (H).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for Q2 - in general it holds for uniformly convex spaces

Comment: Nice, so in particular $L^p$ with $p \not \in \{1, \infty\}$. Is the proof very complicated?

Comment: @anonymous Google "Radon-Riesz Theorem". In particular, see [this](https://faculty.etsu.edu/gardnerr/5210/notes/Radon-Riesz.pdf).

Comment: no, technically it isn't complicated at all, but I don't know if it's very easy to come up with it, requires some ideas. you need the following lemma - if X is uniformly convex, $||x_n|| \leq 1$ and $||x_n + x_m|| \rightarrow 2$ as n, m tend to infinity then $x_n$ is a Cauchy sequence. I can't recall a book in which you can find it, but I suppose that should be included in some functional analysis books

Comment: It's item 15.17 in Hewitt and Stromberg's *Real and Abstract Analysis*. I also recall this theorem was discussed in a post here. I'll try to find it...

Comment: @DavidMitra: That proof (for locally uniformly convex spaces) is very nice!

Comment: According to the diagram in [Megginson, p476], this property (H) is implied by either LUR (locally uniform rotundity) or property (K). (I do not know what that is)

Answer (score 2):

For Q1:  Here's an example in the Banach space $c_0$ of sequences of (real or complex) numbers converging to $0$ with sup norm.  Let $x_n=(1,0,0,\ldots,0,0,1,0,0,\ldots)$, with $1$s in the first and $n^\text{th}$ spots and $0$s elsewhere.  Then $(x_n)$ converges weakly to $x=(1,0,0,\ldots)$, and $\|x_n\|=\|x\|=1$ for all $n$, but $x_n$ does not converge in norm.