# $T_n \rightarrow T$ then we have $||T|| \le \liminf(||T_n||)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

I know how to show that a cauchy sequence of linear continuous operators $T_n:X \rightarrow Y$ has a limit that is also such an operator(if Y is a Banach space), but I found this relation here too $||T|| \le \liminf(||T_n||)$ and I just don't know where this liminf comes into play. Does anybody here know?

Comment: If the sequence is a Cauchy sequence in the norm, you have $\lVert T\rVert = \lim \lVert T_n\rVert$. You get the $\liminf$ if the convergence is not norm-convergence, but for example pointwise convergence (and both spaces should be Banach, although, if you know that the limit exists everywhere, you need not require $Y$ to be complete).

Comment: and how exactly do you see then that it is the liminf?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $(T_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence converging to $T$ (with respect to the operator norm), then we have

$$\lVert T\rVert = \lim_{n\to\infty} \lVert T_n\rVert$$

by the continuity of the norm ($\left\lvert \lVert T\rVert - \lVert S\rVert\right\rvert \leqslant \lVert T-S\rVert$).

You get the $\liminf$ if the convergence is in a different sense, e.g. pointwise convergence (although of course it remains correct in the case of norm convergence, we just have something more precise then).

If $(T_n)$ is a sequence of continuous linear operators $X\to Y$, where $X$ and $Y$ are normed spaces that converges pointwise to a linear operator $T$, and if $M = \liminf\limits_{n\to\infty} \lVert T_n\rVert < \infty$ (if $X$ is a Banach space, a pointwise convergent sequence is uniformly bounded by the Banach-Steinhaus theorem, so the condition is automatically fulfilled; for incomplete $X$, it must be explicitly stated), then $T$ is continuous, and

$$\lVert T\rVert \leqslant M.$$

For, let $x \in X$ with $\lVert x\rVert \leqslant 1$. For every $\varepsilon > 0$, there are infinitely many $n_k$ with $\lVert T_{n_k}\rVert < M + \varepsilon$. Since the subsequence $(T_{n_k})$ also converges pointwise to $T$, we have

$$Tx = \lim_{k\to\infty} T_{n_k}x.$$

But $\lVert T_{n_k}x\rVert < M+\varepsilon$ for all $k$, and hence $\lVert Tx\rVert \leqslant M+\varepsilon$. That holds for all $x$ with $\lVert x\rVert \leqslant 1$, so

$$\lVert T\rVert = \sup_{\lVert x\rVert \leqslant 1} \lVert Tx\rVert \leqslant M + \varepsilon.$$

That holds for all $\varepsilon > 0$, hence $\lVert T\rVert \leqslant M$.

Comment: Not following the part about pointwise convergence. Does it imply that there are operators such that $\lim T_n x = Tx$ but $\lim \|T_n\| \neq \|T\|$? Any good examples?

Comment: Yes, we can have pointwise convergent sequences of operators with $\lVert \lim T_n\rVert < \liminf \lVert T_n\rVert$, for example on $\ell^p$ spaces ($1 \leqslant p < \infty$), we can take $T_n(x) = x_n\cdot e_1$. Then $T_n(x) \to 0$ for all $x$, but $\lVert T_n\rVert = 1$ for all $n$.

Comment: You also get the liminf for weak convergence, since the norm is weakly sequentially lower semicontinuous. You might also find this question interesting: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/417349/characterisation-of-norm-convergence