# Question about difference quotient in Sobolev space

Tags: real-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $u\in W^{1,p}(R)$ be given, $1\leq p<\infty$. We define 
$$ \tau_h(u)(x):=\frac{u(x+h)-u(x)}{h} $$
be the difference quotient.

We all know that up to a subsequence $\tau_h(u)\to u'$ in the weak sense and $\|\tau_h(u)\|_{L^p}\to \|u'\|_{L^p}$.

But my professor claims that 
$$ \|\tau_h(u)-u'\|_{L^p(R)}\to 0 $$
as $h\to 0$.

In the beginning I was trying to use approximation to do it. Let $u_\epsilon$ be sequence of $C_c^\infty$ function such that $u_\epsilon\to u$ in $W^{1,p}$. Of course, we have 
$$ \|\tau_h(u_n)-u_\epsilon'\|_{L^p(R)}\to 0 $$
Hence I was trying to use 
$$  \|\tau_h(u)-u'\|_{L^p(R)}\leq   \|\tau_h(u)-\tau_h(u_n)\|_{L^p(R)}+\|\tau_h(u_n)-u_n'\|_{L^p(R)}+\|u_n'-u'\|_{L^p(R)}$$

However, I can not go future from here because I can NOT control the rate of convergence of term
$$  \|\tau_h(u)-\tau_h(u_n)\|_{L^p(R)}$$
That is, for any $\epsilon>0$ be given, I can only choose $n$ large enough such that 
$$  \|\tau_h(u)-\tau_h(u_n)\|_{L^p(R)}<\epsilon\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(1)$$
for EACH fixed $h$. Next I have to choose $h$ small enough such that 
$$\|\tau_h(u_n)-u_n'\|_{L^p(R)}<\epsilon$$
However, now I lose the central of the part 
$$  \|\tau_h(u)-\tau_h(u_n)\|_{L^p(R)}$$
It may happen that as $h$ gets small, I have to choose a bigger $n$ to maintain $(1)$ hold...and we fall into kind of circular argument...

Any help is really welcome!

Update: for case $p=2$ here is a quick prove. Since we know that, up to a subsequence, $\tau_h(u)\to u'$ in the weak sense and $\|\tau_h(u)\|_{L^2}\to \|u'\|_{L^2}$. Hence, by $L^2$ is a Hilbert space we actually have 
$$ \|\tau_h(u)-u'\|_{L^2(R)}\to 0. $$

But the same argument can not hold if $p\neq 2$, since it is not a Hilbert space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the fact that $L^p$ spaces are a Radon-Riesz spaces, for p>1. and the case $p=1$ i don't have a proof but you can use the fact that each of the $L^p$-spaces,
$1 ≤ p < ∞$, has the property that each sequence on the unit sphere that converges
almost everywhere converges also in norm.

Comment: Can you provide me a reference that $L^p$ is a Radon-Reisz space? Thx!

Comment: You can see [This page ](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/417349/characterisation-of-norm-convergence)

Comment: Right. I also find this on H. Brasiz's book. It called Strict Convex space. Thx!